System & Installed apps are not working in Ubuntu 22.04.4
I switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm facing very strange errors. Sometimes my applications won't respond (won't open) e.g. VSCode, Firefox, and sometimes even Chrome won't open. Also, even the system-install app does the same e.g. Ubuntu Software app is not working. When I click on the application, it simply gives me no response not even the app's screen or app's name appear on the screen and taskbar respectively.
I don't understand what happened to them. In the menu bar these app's icons are also removed and just names are there.
Is there any fix for this? Do I need to install Ubuntu again or do I need to update my Ubuntu version?


If an application does not run by click try to launch it through the terminal. Then you will see the cause.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Ok, move it to comments.
